# Print & Print Preview a Bitmap plus a Label with Text in it in c#

Tags: c#, text, printing, picturebox, print-preview

I have made a function in my program that will print off bitmaps and a image from a picturebox, but now want to print a label with text in it as well. This is my current code:

```
private void printToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
    printDocument1.Print();
  }
}

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(capturebox.BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
   e.ToString(ExtraNotes.Text);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(capturebox.Image, 0, 0);    
 }
```

My label is called ExtraNotes, and my picturebox is capturebox.

I want to be able to print both of these with the label contents either to the side or below the image, i don't mind.

I also want to be able to print preview this using a print preview dialog of which i don't know how to make show this, i can get it to open but not show the things i want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(capturebox.BackgroundImage, 0, 0);
   e.DrawString(ExtraNotes.Text, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
   e.Graphics.DrawImage(capturebox.Image, 0, 0);    
 }
```

You can change the corrdinates of where you want the text to go.

Comment: This still comes up with an error that the printpageeventargs does not contain the definition of drawstring??

Comment: Don't worry, i just had to make the e.DrawString(ExtraNotes.Text, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10); to e.Graphics.DrawString(ExtraNotes.Text, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);

Comment: Oops; forgot to type Graphics.